# Excel VBA Delete Rows Containing certain text. Code not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that opens a workbook. I want it to then look into column C and if it finds anything with the text "Draft", delete the entire row. This is my code which does not appear to give me any errors but it does not delete the rows like I want.  What am I missing?

```
enter code here
Dim i As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("Archer Search Report")
For i = 2 To FinalRow
If Range("C" & i).Value = "Draft" Then
    Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim i As Long, finalRow As Long

    finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Archer Search Report")
    For i = finalRow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("C" & i).Value = "Draft" Then
            Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Notes:

- It's best to work backwards (`Step -1`) when deleting otherwise it messes with the row count
- I prefer `EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!  I'll remember the Step -1 in the future.